# Роутинг при помощи java web server Jetty

Tags: java, jetty

Я достаточно долгое время писал весь бэкэнд на Jetty с использованием только сервлетов. (jsp не тогал так как не было необходимости)
Недавно меня попросили добавить некоторые фичи в уже имеющийся проект на php/laravel. Начав разбираться что это за фреймворк (laravel) я наткнулся на очень приятную фичу -- роутинг и контроллеры. И тут у меня появилось желание использовать такой же механизм в своих Jetty серверах.
Коротко: я хочу примерно такое:

```
//...
Route::get("/", "MainController@index");
Route::get("/{postId}", "MainController@SinglePost");
Route::any("/test", function () {
    return "<h2>test</h2>";
});
//...
Route::get("/events/add", "EventController@showCreateForm"); // при get запросе возвращаем юзеру форму для заполнения
Route::post("/events/add", "EventController@addEvent"); // при post запросе добавляем данные, отправленные юзером
```

Мне подобный стиль организации запросов на сервере сильно понравился и я решил погуглить подобную надстройку для Jetty. В итоге я получил [bladejava](http://bladejava.com/) и [spark](http://sparkjava.com/), поняв что этих библиотек не одна, я решил написать сюда. *Подскажите, какие из подобных библиотек ещё есть и какая из них лучше.*

Comment: стандарт де-факто в Java-мире - либо Spring MVC, либо одна из реализаций JAX-RS (Jersey/CXF/RESTEasy)